# Equivalent of Turn Restrictions in Arc GIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, turns

In ArcMap when I open a Network Dataset I see

[image]

In ArcGIS Pro I see

[image]

I had a look at the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/what-is-network-dataset-.htm) and can't find anything about this change.

How do I add turn restrictions in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [An overview of the Turn Feature Class toolset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/network-analyst/an-overview-of-the-turn-feature-class-toolset.htm) in the ArcGIS Pro online help:

> The Turn Feature Class toolset contains tools used to build and edit
> turn data. The tools in the toolset allow you to create new turn
> feature classes, convert existing ArcView GIS or ArcInfo Workstation
> turn tables to turn feature classes, and maintain the integrity of
> existing turn features based on their geometry or an alternate ID
> field in cases when the reference source features are updated.

Comment: What I don't understand is that the turn ND is in the gdb already but pro doesn't show it. Do we have to create a new one or create the whole ND from scratch in Pro eventhough it's already in the dataset created by ArcMap?

Comment: I haven’t built a network dataset in a while and never for ArcGIS Pro but if one was built in ArcMap and it didn’t just work in ArcGIS Pro my first inclination would be to re-build it using the latest software.

Comment: In the end, I worked out that it's just a visual thing. ArcMap brings in all the features that are part of a network dataset, Pro doesn't do this but still uses them all. You just have to add them to the map manually.